# Streamlit upload file got 400 error with invalid session_id response

Tags: azure-devops, streamlit, session-state

I have a similar issue like https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/4173 this ticket. It's deployed on Kubernetes there. In my case, I deploy it on azure. And I already set my session affinity on from Auzre portal. But I still got same error.
[image]
[image]